# Lock Screen Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I just upgraded to iOS 8.0.2. Now there is a permanent keyboard on the lower half of my screen in locked mode and on home screen. The keyboard will pop up every time I receive a text message and it will cause the home screen to lock up.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Had you enabled any 3rd party keyboards from the appstore? If so, did you try disabling them?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to *Settings*, then *Password*. Enter your lock screen password. Swipe down there are radio buttons under a heading that reads *Allow access when locked*. The last one is *Reply with message*. Try turning that one off.

If problem persists and you want an annoying non(long-term)solution, you can swipe right directly on the lock screen text to get a reply square. Selecting this will allow you to close out of the lock screen text and give you full access to the password entry screen so that you don't have to restart your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well when using a Bluetooth keyboard with my iPad Air (iOS 8.0.2).

As soon as I disconnect the keyboard, the software keyboard will pop up on screen, regardless whether the context allows text entry.

The keyboard responds to input (key press), but even when having an application such as Notes open, typing doesn't do anything. I've noticed that when you split the keyboard in two, it will actually reveal a second keyboard behind it for a split second.

The only workaround I've found is to hard reset the iPad by holding both the home button and the lock button for ten seconds (until the Apple logo appears). After that, the permanent on-screen keyboard disappears.